# Cleaner XCode macro for this

Tags: ios, xcode, coding-style, macros

Currently I am using something like this for ARC compatibility between iOS 4.0~4.3:

```
- (void) viewDidUnload {
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED > __IPHONE_4_3
#else
    //set outlets to nil
#endif
}
```

The #if<->#else area is always empty. So my question is this. Is there a cleaner way to write the #if line so I don't need the #else statement? I tried to use "<" but it didn't seem to understand.

Comment: Why don't you set your outlets to `nil` in 5.0+? It doesn't hurt to do it.

Comment: Because I like shiny new toys :)

Comment: Sure, but deleting code only to add it back inside a conditional compilation directive doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: What about in the future when I don't need to support OS versions below 4.3? With this method I can run one search and immediately find all the affected code (and in this case do nothing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I can now answer my own question. Brace yourselves:

Take

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED > __IPHONE_4_3
#else
    //set outlets to nil
#endif
```

and replace it with

```
#if __IPHONE_4_3 > __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED 
    //set outlets to nil
#endif
```

It seems the compiler doesn't support < in macros.